# How do I add values to class objects then put them in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I'm trying to embed queries into the variables in the class.
Like so:

```
    class FooBar{
        public $bar;
    }


    $result = array();

    $db = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "foo", "foo", "Farm");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `Lot`;";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $foo = new FooBar;            
        $foo->$bar = $row["cow"];

        array_push($result, $foo);
    }
```

But when I print the array using `print_r($result)`, I'm just getting this as an output:

```
Array( )
```

I was hoping to see the objects stored in the array.

Where did I go wrong? What should I be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reusing the `$result` variable. It's an an array but you reuse it as a MySQLi resource.

Also `$foo->$bar` should be `$foo->bar`.

```
class FooBar{
    public $bar;
}


$result = array();

$db = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "foo", "foo", "Farm");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `Lot`;";
$query_result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result)){
    $foo = new FooBar;            
    $foo->bar = $row["cow"];

    array_push($result, $foo);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: (facepalms) I should've paid attention. Thank you :)

Comment: I think PHP should give you a warning for trying to use a MySQLi resource as an array. Make sure you have your error level turned up in development.

Comment: I thought it wouldn't matter because I am storing the returned result in the array, not the MySQL query.